# How to set MetaFlow's --max-workers flag from within Python definition?

Tags: python, environment-variables, command-line-interface, netflix-metaflow

MetaFlow permits you to [set the maximum number of concurrent tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60176593/4212158) using the `--max-workers` CLI flag (ref: https://docs.metaflow.org/metaflow/scaling#safeguard-flags). However, I would like to avoid setting this every time.

Is it possible to set the `--max-workers` flag from the Python definition of the FlowSpec (without the CLI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI flag sets the `METAFLOW_RUN_MAX_WORKERS` environment variable. You can set this within Python by setting this environment variable before you define your FlowSpec:

```py
# force MetaFlow to use only 1 concurrent task during a foreach fanout
os.environ.update({"METAFLOW_RUN_MAX_WORKERS": "1"})
```

Source: chat with @Savin